# Convert from NSDictionary to [String:Any?]

Tags: swift, eureka-forms

I am using xmartlabs/Eureka to build an app with a dynamic form.

In order to fill the form I have to use `setValues(values: [String: Any?])`.

But I have the form values in an `NSDictionary` variable  and I cannot cast it to `[String:Any?]`.

Is there a way to convert an `NSDictionary` to `[String:Any?]` ?

Comment: `and I cannot cast it to [String:Any?]`  What have you tried?  What didn't work?  How did you try casting it and what was the problem exactly?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Hope this helps:

```
let dict = NSDictionary()
var anyDict = [String: Any?]()

for (value, key) in dict {
    anyDict[key as! String] = value
}
```

Comment: I fix your code and it works now:

`let dict = NSDictionary()
var anyDict = [String: Any?]()

for (value, key) in dict {
    anyDict[key as! String] = value
}`

Comment: @ZuhairAli This is bit ridiculous to accept a wrong answer only to fix it yourself later. :) You should have written your own answer with the correct code instead.

Comment: To add... shouldn't this be (key, value) instead of the other way around?

Comment: ***for (key, value)*** , NOT ***for (value, key)***

Answer (score 3):

Just an example:

```
if let content = data["data"] as? [String:AnyObject] {
    print(content)
}
```

The data is a JSON object here. Use it accordingly.